# How to create a MySQL database connection on Dbeaver

Tags: mysql

I am running mysql db as a docker image and everything was built correctly. My Mysql image is running and I can see the container id but when I try to establish a connection on my workbench I get this error - "Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to the Driver properties tab and set allowPublicKeyRetrieval to true. More details at MySQL Connection error with default Driver Properties https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/9565#issuecomment-680773545
This should fix ur issues...